# MySQL Syntax Error on complicated query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax

Sorry for the derp question (as I'm sure it probably is), but after going over the manual and through Stack Overflow for answer on this one, I'm still unsure of what's wrong with this database query.

Some info:
I'm trying to create a function that creates an array of all zipcodes within a radius around another zipcode.  I'm using this as reference: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html

I have actually had this string working on my live site, however I'm now redoing some work on my localhost (WAMP) which is running MySQL 5.5.24.  The platform is Wordpress.

I understand that quotes (or a lack thereof) around database names, fields, etc and I've used several variations with no luck at all.

Anyways, enough talk.  Here's the error:

```
[You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''geo_data' WHERE 'Lat>44.566' AND 'Lat<44.566' AND 'Lon>-109.208' AND 'L' at line 4]
```

And here's the code:

```
SELECT 'Postcode', 'Lat', 'Lon', 'acos(sin($lat)*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos($lat)*cos(radians(Lat))*cos(radians(Lon)-$lon))*$R' AS D
        FROM (
            SELECT 'Postcode', 'Lat', 'Lon'
            FROM 'geo_data'
            WHERE 'Lat>$minLat' AND 'Lat<$maxLat'
            AND 'Lon>$minLon' AND 'Lon<$maxLon'
        ) 
        AS 'firstcut' 
        WHERE 'acos(sin($lat)*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos($lat)*cos(radians(Lat))*cos(radians(Lon)-$lon))*$R' < '$rad'
        ORDER BY 'D'
```

Thanks for the help, sorry again if I'm missing the obvious.

### EDIT

Thanks guys!  Got it working.  Here's the working code for the benefit of others:

```
SELECT `Postcode`, `Lat`, `Lon`, acos(sin($lat)*sin(radians(`Lat`)) + cos($lat)*cos(radians(`Lat`))*cos(radians(`Lon`)-$lon))*$R AS `D`
        FROM (
            SELECT `Postcode`, `Lat`, `Lon`
            FROM `geo_data`
            WHERE `Lat`>'$minLat' AND `Lat`<'$maxLat'
            AND `Lon`>'$minLon' AND `Lon`<'$maxLon'
        ) 
        AS `firstcut` 
        WHERE acos(sin($lat)*sin(radians(`Lat`)) + cos($lat)*cos(radians(`Lat`))*cos(radians(`Lon`)-$lon))*$R < '$rad'
        ORDER BY `D`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using single quotes `'` around your field and table names.  This is incorrect.  You want to use backticks `` ` ``.  Using quotes makes MySQL interpret it as a string.

You also have your conditions and calculations inside quotes, that just makes them into strings.

For example, your inner query should look like this:

```
SELECT `Postcode`, `Lat`, `Lon`
FROM `geo_data`
WHERE `Lat > '$minLat' AND `Lat` < '$maxLat'
AND `Lon`> '$minLon' AND `Lon` < '$maxLon'
```

Comment: Much thanks!  I was afraid it would be something like that; silly oversight on my part.  The error is gone; I'll post the corrected string in my initial question for future reference.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

'geo_data' is a string `geo_data` [with backticks (`)] is a tablename